# C++ library integration with Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, c++, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am bringing up an old discussion we had on the ionic forum.

I wanted to integrate some C/C++ libraries to my Ionic app.

Is it possible to integrate with C/C++ libraries?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your target Platform you would need to write a cordova plugin that integrates your C/C++ Library for the desired platform. Afterwards you can use the plugin in your ionic application.

As far as I know, this is the only possibility for you to integrate native Code into your Ionic Application.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about how to go about that? Writing a plugin that does that? This will be my first time

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin [cordova-plugin-cpp-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cpp-bridge) that makes C++ integration relatively straightforward. However, I don't think it has support for native library dependencies. If you have all your source files you should be fine then.